# "Вселенная" образована от "вселённая"?

Tags: этимология

Правда ли, что существительное "вселенная" образовано от причастия "вселённая" (заселённая)?

Answer (score 1):

В этимологическом онлайн-словаре Успенского Л. В.:

Вселе́нная. Это заимствование из старославянского языка, а в нем оно было калькой древнегреческого «ойкуменэ» — «обитаемый мир» (вероятно, все вы читали повесть И. Ефремова «На краю Ойкумены»). Старославянское происхождение слова видно сразу: русская форма звучала бы — «вселённая».

Лучше не объяснишь.